# Is there any difference between "woanders" and "irgendwo"?

Tags: difference

A German friend gave me three example sentences with "woanders" and "irgendwo", and I wonder if there is any difference in meaning among them.

"Ich gehe woanders hin", "Ich gehe irgendwo hin", "Ich gehe irgendwo anders hin."

Comment: What specific question remains after having consulted the dictionary of your choice? I'm somewhat tempted to close the qeustion in its present form...

Comment: I have no more questions to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They definitely mean different things. Approximate equivalents in English:

- woanders = elsewhere; i.e. in/to a place other than the one we are now in or the one previously mentioned
- irgendwo = somewhere/anywhere; i.e. in/to an arbitrary unknown unmentioned place
- irgendwo anders = somewhere/anywhere else; i.e. in/to an arbitrary unknown unmentioned place that is different from the one we are now in or the one previously mentioned

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The words emphasize different aspects. *Woanders* emphasizes that the place in question is somewhere else. It could be "somewhere else than here", but it could also be a comparison to another place. For example:

> A: Ich gehe zum Markt, willst du mitkommen?
>
> B: Nein, ich muss noch woanders hin.

Here, B is saying that they have to go to a place other than the market, which is why they can't join A.

On the other hand, *irgendwo* is stressing the arbitrariness of the place.

Comment: Thank you so much!